# Not able to export the data from web form in .csv format via using chrome browser

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, csv, google-apps-script

Our application is deployed on google, we are struggling while downloading the report into excel format. Total data which is there in application is around 5000 (in the form of rows). But when we apply filter then the data is downloaded, file size is around 2 MB.

Is there chrome restriction that it does not support > 2 MB file download? Below is the issue which we get in return.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)**

Can anybody help me out to resolve the issue please.